# Create an android widget with viewpager and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-widget, android-viewpager

Does anyone of you know how to create an android home-screen widget using the ViewPager and fragments ?

Any help would be really appreciated!
thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone of you know how to create an android home-screen widget using the ViewPager and fragments ?

You cannot use `ViewPager` or `Fragment` in a home screen app widget. [The documentation lists what is available to you](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) in the `RemoteViews` that is used to create an app widget.

Comment: I've looked at that but i didn't find how to create a scroll-able list that enables the users to drag with his finger from left to wright and the opposite(exactly as viewpager and fragment).
ps: the widget in question is to display articles, and the user scroll from one article to an other...
what you think is the better solution for this and thank you!

Comment: I've tried to use standard **listview** but i don't want that two items be displayed at the same time...

Comment: @user3192021: "I've looked at that but i didn't find how to create a scroll-able list that enables the users to drag with his finger from left to wright and the opposite" -- that's not possible in an app widget. `StackView` is the closest match, but only works in one direction. "the widget in question is to display articles" -- since most app widgets are only a couple of centimeters on a side, I fail to see how this will be practical.

Comment: it's a widget for a news application, the user could scroll from one article(just a brief description, the image and the title) to an other and when he clicks on one of them it opens the app and *fully display the clicked article*...

Comment: @user3192021: Particularly if you have an image per article, I'd go with `StackView`.